# How can I add an attribute to a third-party Python class?

Tags: python, django, class

I'm working with a third-party Python/Django package.  I'd like to an an attribute to all instances of a class (specifically a created_on auto-timestamp).  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Assuming subclassing is not an option?

Comment: subclassing is probably the correct way to do this ...

Comment: I recommend doing something else to track this data.

Comment: I'm using Django--this is not a major deal, but if I were to subclass I don't really want both classes to appear in the admin.  Since it's a third-party, the parent class was automatically there.

Comment: @thumbtackthief, use `admin.site.unregister(ParentModel)` on the parent class to remove it from the admin